# Tag Manager Lookup Table change comma to decimal point

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, lookup-tables

i have a problem with Facebook Donations and Fundraising. The Amount is written with comma but i need it in decimal point to match the data with data from other sources in my German Google Analytics Account. The Data from other sources is written the german way with decimal point.

Is there a way to convert the data from facebook with comma (10,000) into german data with decimal point (10.000) with a Google Tag Manager Lookup Table?

Answer (score 2):

So I think you can create a variable with Custom Javascript and do a str.replace of "," to "." and THEN send that to GA?

Comment: That's a much better idea than using a lookup table (as asked by the OP), which would require a line for every possible amount.